# How can I make a layover GUI for Android Unity game

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have made an Android game using Unity, and now for the finishing touch I need a nice GUI, but unlike a GUI that just takes place in a different Unity scene, I would like it to just be a layover in the scene where the game is played. Basically you can see the game in the background, but there is a GUI with some buttons like setting and play. Say you click play, then the GUI would go away and the game would begin. Is this something that can be done in Unity? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Bonus question - best way to make a good looking GUI, should I design it myself or should I buy from the Unity Asset Store? Pros and Cons of each?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the ui in the same scene as your game using the new unity ui system and the canvas object. Than for example on play button click you just aniamte the ui outside of the visible area or remove it from the canvas.